# can anyone explain Late binding in java for me please?

Tags: java

in late binding, I know which method or object going to use, isn't done at compile time, the choice is made during the run time.

by how does it work in the JVM level, I want to know details in low level, and why its called late binding, not something like real-time choosing etc.....

Comment: why people vote is down? is it because the question isn't clear? or its too simple, or its not worth knowing ?

Comment: I think it was voted down, because you could have googled for the answer like I did, or searched for an existing question on this forum or otherwise. Your question showed you did no prior research. If it is any consolation, I didn't vote down. I've learned to research prior to posting a question. It shows motivation and work, rather than simply waiting for an answer.

Comment: if everything can be solved by simply googleing this world soon will be a better place.  its called late binding but bind to what? such information is't easy to be find. everyone drink water every day doesn't mean everyone knows waters chemical and physical properties, or simply why its called water. the fact that you drink it everyday, does't makes the question easier, or let you automaticlly knowing the answer

Answer (score 1):

Found some links for you from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) and from [Geek Explains](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/dynamic-binding-vs-static-binding-in.html) that talk about late binding. And if you really want to know low level, then you are probably best to read the [JVM specification document](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html).